# AS3 - about movie clips

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, movieclip

Take a look at this code:

```
var balls:Array = new Array();
var mc:ball = new ball();
addChild(mc);
balls.push(mc);
```

Well, I've just created a movie clip called **mc** and added it to the stage. Since every movieclip is created with the same name '**mc**', why can I work on individual movie clips just by pushing it into an array? Like, balls[0] is gonna be my first movieclip. Why couldn't I create:

```
for...
var balls[n]:ball = new ball();
```

And then treat every single ball like `ball[0]`, `ball[1]`, etc...?
Why do I have to add it to an array or assign a different name for each one, making it unique?

Also, how can I create an object from a class that automatically creates a ball, and then when i delete this object, I delete the ball too?

I want to understand what exactly a movieclip means in AS3.

Thanks

Comment: It's very hard to tell what exactly you're asking. This question also seems to be several questions combined.

Comment: This is the kind of question I expect when people look at code examples etc and don't take the time to learn basic fundamental programming concepts first. What is scope ? What is a local variable ? What is a reference ? It's not saving time to avoid learning these concepts. You ultimately waste many hours/days/weeks wondering and floundering.

Comment: I answered this, but if you want to commit yourself to learn this language, then please get this [book](http://www.amazon.com/Essential-ActionScript-3-0-Colin-Moock/dp/0596526946). There also might be a free PDF form of it, but im not sure. Either you are an armature programmer for the rest of your life, or you take a couple of months to really study and become a great programmer for the rest of your life. Its really up to you.

Comment: I have to disagree with Xiler, that book it's a great reference book, but not a great learning tool. It won't teach you to program at all. This is a much better book for beginners: http://www.amazon.com/Learning-ActionScript-3-0-Beginners-Guide/dp/B008SLIR8A

Comment: Well i just assumed that he had prior programming knowledge, If not then the book that i referenced is hard to learn programming from. But once you are comfortable with basic programming techniques, then I highly recommend the book i referenced, as it fully explains the fundamentals of OOP, which is what thing question was really about and what Actionscript 3.0 is all about also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried as best I can to interpret and answer yours question. If you feel that the first part of my answer is too much of a review, please stick to it and read it all, it will help you understand the rest of it. All of it in inside the code - so read through the comments.

```
new Object();  //Creates a new object  that is now in the memory of the computer
var object:Object = new Object(); // Create a new object, and at the same time 
// assigns a reference, which is to it (object).
// This reference will allow you to refer to the created object, later in the code.
var mc:MovieClip = new MovieClip(); // Creates a advanced object called MovieClip
// MovieClips are just objects that can do more, like for instance they have the
//ability to be displayed on screen, so that the user can see them
addChild(mc) // Adds the movieclip created above to the display list, so that it is not 
//only in the computer's memory, but visible to the user
var array:Array = new Array() // Creates an Array object. This object is just like the
//MovieClip except it just can't be displayed. But unlike the MovieClip, it is a
//reference list to other objects, that you push into it.
array.push(mc);
// This command makes the first slot in the array have a reference to our mc that we
//created earliet.
array.push(new MovieClip());
// THIS is very important, this line first creates a movieclip object, but then instead
//of letting it get lost in the computer's memory, it passes it into the array.push
//function, so that its added on to the array.
// BOTH mc and array[0] now refer to the same object, changing mc.x property to 0,
//changes the array[0].x property to 0.
// To get to your question, you can bypass the variable mc completely by doing this:
array = new Array();
for(var i:int = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    array.push(new MovieClip());
    addChild(array[array.length - 1]);
}
// THIS code creates an array object, sets up a loop that will loop through 10 times;
//and on every iteration of the loop, the array adds another new MovieClip to its list,
//and then right away adds it to the display list to be viewed by the user.

// NOW to have a class automatically create a ball is a weird thing because this can
//mean so many diferent things.
// This can mean that new objects from this class, create balls that are its display
//children, or it can mean that this class is a ball itself, or that it has only one
//ball as a display child... etc.
// What I think what you mean is: how have a class automatically look like a ball,
//whenever i make an instance of it.
// This can be acheive by setting up the class the accept parameters in its
//constructor, that define how the ball will look. And by using the graphic property of
// the display object, It will set it self up to look like a ball, when it is later
// added to the display list.
```

Below is the ball class:

```
package {
import flash.display.MovieClip;

public class ball extends MovieClip { // EXTENDS MovieClip just means that it takes
//all the powers that the MovieClip class has and applies it to its self, so now this
//class is not only JUST like a MovieClip, but also has the stuff that we put into it
//in this class definition.

    private const defaultRadius:Number = 10;
    private const defaultColor:Number = 0xFF0000;

    public function ball(radius:Number=defaultRadius,color:Number=defaultColor):void {
//ALL display objects have a graphic property, this just lets you "paint" the object so
//that it has some stuff to show when it is displayed.
        this.graphics.beginFill(color, 1);
        this.graphics.drawCircle(0, 0, radius);
        this.graphics.endFill();
    }
}
}
```

To use it we would just create it like any other object, but also pass parameters to its constructor. We don't have to pass parameters, but if we don't want those default sizes and colors to be applied to our ball, then we better replace them with different ones.

```
array = new Array();
for(var i:int = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    array.push(new ball(15,0x0000FF));
    addChild(array[array.length - 1]);
}
// Creates 10 balls that have a 15 radius and are blue. We also then make them
//displayable.
```

Please, if you're question has been answered, then accept this answer and maybe upvote it, but if not, then please respond with a more detailed question that I can better understand and then better explain an answer. Thanks

Comment: Is there a way that I can 'addChild' directly from the Class? If this is possible, then can I add an existing movieclip from library?

Comment: You can use addChild to add an instance of a class from the library to your ball class, sure. But why wouldn't you just create the class from the library directly. You can actually go to your movieclip from the library and change its class code so that: 1) You can draw how it looks via flash professional CS6 2) change its class so that you can control its behavior. If you want an example of this then just tell me and I can post another question to answer it. But just please explain more so that I can answer more.

Answer (score 0):

It's this way

```
for...
balls[n] = new ball();
```

or

```
balls.push(new ball());
```

Simple, isn't it?

Comment: `var array[index] = value` is not valid syntax. Remove the leading `var` keyword.

Comment: Ooops... that's what happens when you copy and paste... Thanks!